# How to send a replacement transaction with a higher gas price?

Tags: web3js, transactions, gas, pending-transactions

I am sending a transaction with sendSignedTransaction :

```
const tx = new Tx({
   ...
   "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(41 * 1e9),
   ...
}

await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx)
  .on('transactionHash', (hash) => { 
      console.log('waiting....'); 
  })
  .on('receipt', (receipt) => { 
      console.log('... Transaction validated !');
  });
```

It works fine. Here is what i want to do:

- I want to set a very low value for gasPrice: For example 41 gwei
- If the transaction is not validated after 15 seconds, i want to increase gasPrice to 51 gwei
- etc.

How can I do that programmatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the same transaction but with a different `tx['gasPrice']`, if the new transaction has the same `tx['nonce']` then the transacition with an higher gas price will be added to the next block by the miners and so the old one will be automatically discarded .

However 15 seconds is a very small time interval, maybe it's better to resend the transaction at every new block (currently the average block time is about 13 seconds) setting the gas price to a percentage of the previous block gas price and trying to increment this percentage at every new block.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 15 second was an example. I know this is possible to send the same transaction with same nonce but i want to know if there is a best way to do that ? Because it will cost gas...

Comment: The gas is consumed only if the transaction gets added to a block, the gas you'll spend is the gas used by the transaction with the higher gas price.

Comment: Thanks but why should we pay gas for canceling a pending transaction in metamask ?

Comment: Cancelling a pending transaction means submitting an empty transaction with a value of 0 Ether (it costs 21000 gas) and the same nonce but an higher gas price, miners simply ignore the transaction with a lower gas price.
Replacing a transaction is the same but the new transacion is not empty.

Comment: @AndreaCiceri sounds good. Could you update you answer with code example using web3js which will cancel or replace pending tx.